# How to judge the classification performance of relevant vector machine according to the image?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, rvm

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

As shown in these two pictures,they are plotted based on the same database and two different algorithms.One algorithm is RVM,and the other is promoted RVM.How can I judge the performance according to the two pictures?

Comment: You need to have a ground truth. How could you know if your classification is correct otherwise ?

Comment: After you have a ground truth it is common to present a precision- recall plot.

Comment: Maybe my description is not clear.I know the precision and recall of this two pictures.They are nearly the same,but obviously, the pictures plotted from the result seem a little different.I wonder if we can obtain some other information to judge the performance of the two algorithms from the pictures.Such as its generalization quality or some other features.@obchardon  @itzik Ben Shabat